# bind a model to list in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How we can bind a model to list in mvc 4 ?

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx I found it myself on phill hack article..

Comment: Here is an usfull article<br>
[Bind Model Example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159749/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-Part1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159749/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-Part1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a MVC Project, leave everything default and add Product in your Models folders with the following (very simple) code:

```
namespace BlogPost.Models
{
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Then add a ProductsController (in the Controllers folder) with the following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BlogPost.Models;

namespace BlogPost.Controllers
{
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Add(IList<Product> products)
    {
        return this.View();
    }
 }
}
```

Source: http://kristofmattei.be/2009/10/19/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-to-a-list/